# Hoverfly API Simulations with Golang repositories: how to get started

Tags: go, hoverfly

I have just started to experiment with [Hoverfly](https://docs.hoverfly.io/en/latest/index.html) and I have a Golang backend calling a number of 3rd party APIs for which I would need to create simulations. I am aware that Hoverfly has Java and Py bindings and I have come across a number of tutorials using Hoverfly with both. I think I am possibly missing very trivial point here, once I have created the simulations (via the Capture Mode), what is the next step? Do I simply create integration tests making use of them? Do you import the go package [here](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/SpectoLabs/hoverfly) into my repository? I was looking for some sample usages in the examples folder and I have seen more .py driven ones. Is there any available example that I totally missed out?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Golang testing, you can have a look at the functional tests in the hoverfly project: https://github.com/SpectoLabs/hoverfly/tree/master/functional-tests, it’s using hoverfly to test hoverfly!